# File wont delete from trash even after sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/

Tags: command-line, 12.04, trash, rm

I've tried using `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/files/` and even going myself as root doing the same, and recreating the folder its still there, it was from a pendrive at one point and I deleted it but now I cant get it to delete permanently.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart the user trash, there could be a trash for every mounted filesystem.
Run the following command to see:

```
mount | awk '$1 ~ /^\// {print $3}' | while read dir; do find "$dir"/.Trash* 2>&-; done
```

Comment: I really like the „magic” put into this single line of code.