# I accidentally removed my Trash and can longer put items into it, how can I get it back?

Tags: command-line, trash

I did a stupid thing. I was having issues with certain files in my trash that my system was not allowing my to delete, meaning I could no longer empty my trash. These were not super important files, just theme folders I was creating and ditching. After getting frustrated, I googled it and was led to executing this script  `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*`which looks as though it totally removed my trash...completely and now I can no longer add items to it. How can I restore my trash once again? I know it's probably as simple as re-creating the file, but I'm unsure of the terminal language to do this.

Thanks in advance.

TL;DR I removed my trash directory with `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*`and need help getting it back/making a new one.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
cd ~
mkdir .local/share/Trash
mkdir .local/share/Trash/expunged
mkdir .local/share/Trash/files
mkdir .local/share/Trash/info
chmod -R 700 .local/share/Trash
```

... and then restart nautilus with `nautilus -q`. I am not sure it will work, it is just recreating the structure I have with an empty trash; you can safely ignore error about existing directory.

Notice, no `sudo` here. The trash is yours, should be manageable without superuser privileges; as a general rule, you should never use `sudo` to manage file in your home directory --- unless you have to fix previous `sudo` usage, that is.

If you have messed with superuser in this dirs, you may need to fix the ownership...

```
sudo chown -R myuser .local/share/Trash
```

Where `myuser` is your normal user, of course.

And BTW, the "not erasable file" was probably a [file in another partition](https://askubuntu.com/a/109342/16395).

Comment: No need to give `~` argument to `cd` — it defaults to home if run without arguments.

Comment: @Ruslan you are right --- and probably `mkdir -m 700 -p ~/.local/share/Trash/{expunged,files,info}` would work in most shells, but call it defensive shell commanding ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I was repeatedly told in terminal cannot create directory bc it already exists. When I navigate to .local/share/trash I can see the folders expunger, files and info. Files ans info have root permissions so I think that's the problem. How can I change this?

Comment: @Rmano `mkdir -p ~/.local/share/Trash && cd ~/.local/share/Trash && mkdir expunged files info && chmod -R 700 .`

Comment: @gastronomin, I edited the answer. Hope it works...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Ubuntu 14.04 : Thrash opened, but it was not possible to delete anything from it. I installed of the Ubuntu repository program BleachBit, I launched it, and the problem was solved.